# System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize encloses the return string in double quotes

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization

`System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize` encloses the return string in double quotes.

I guess I could remove the first and last character from the return string but was wondering what is the purpose of doing this.

Is there anything I could to make the serializer exclude them by default?

```
string linkCipherString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<byte[]>(linkCipherBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter to strip quotes:

```cs
public class StringJsonConverter: JsonConverter<String>
{
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => reader.GetString();
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value.Replace("\"", ""));
}

var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new StringJsonConverter() } };
JsonSerializer.Serialize(linkCipher, serializeOptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

`JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(object)` would generate the json string like below:

```
"{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"aaa\"}"
```

String literals are of type string and can be written in two forms, quoted and `@`-quoted.This is by design in C#,you could not change it.You could only remove the double quote within the string data like `\"`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-string-type